# DataTable (jQuery) remove last child

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have the following question: I have a DataTable(jQuery) that I order by the first column descending. What I'm trying to do is to remove the last row if the count (Ex. 10) has been reached so the table will never exceed 10 rows. 
I have tried a few ways all with no success. Any help would be appreciated.

UPDATE: For some reason it only removes the first row.

```
    // This is where I assign the DataTable to a variable.
    var unprintedTable = $('#unprinted-table').DataTable({
           "order": [
               [1, "desc"]
           ]
    });

    var unprintedLogLength = 5;
    var unprintedLogCount = 0; // Incremented when a new row is added.

    if (unprintedLogCount > unprintedLogLength) {
        unprintedTable.row($(this).parent('tr:last-child')[0]).remove();
    }
```

Comment: What is the current context? What is `this`?

Comment: `$(this).parent('tr:last-child')[0]` here is your problem. this = every cell? tr => take last cell of every row => [0] only take the first found in this selection? = last cell of the first row

Comment: You do realize DataTable has an option to define the number of records allowed per page, right? https://datatables.net/reference/option/pageLength

Answer (score 0):

Try This One

```
  <button onclick="RemoveLastRow()">Remove Last Row</button>
    <table id="MyTable" class="table table-bordered table-striped" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Column 1</th>
                <th>Column 2</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td><button class="Mybtn">Click me</button></td>
                <td>Hello</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>

    <script>
        var Dtable;
        $(document).ready(function () {
            Dtable = $("#MyTable").DataTable();
        });


        function RemoveLastRow() {
            Dtable.row(Dtable.data().length).remove().draw(false);         
         );
    </script>
```